# Make list of links with background images 1 row desktop, two column on the same devices

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a generated instagram feed with `links`. I want to keep `1 column` on desktop and on the other devices (tablet, desktop) `2 column`. I can use bootstrap, the problem is that the `html` structure is generated after, so I can't make a `row` between two items to make two column (only show the first item structure). You can see a live example [here](http://residenciarucab.es/rucab/index.php). Now it's shows that way on mobile but unordered:

[image]

HTML STRUCTURE:

```
<div class="container-fluid mx-auto insta-feed">
      <h2>INSTAGRAM</h2>
    <div id="instafeed">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
    var userFeed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'user',
        userId: '5388417298',
        accessToken: '5388417298.1677ed0.e3460b92c6f445c98d18f18635f740cf',
  template: '<a href="{{link}}" class="in-img" target="_blank" id="{{id}}" style="background-image: url({{image}});"></a>',
  sortBy: 'most-recent',
  limit: 4,
resolution: 'standard_resolution',

    });
    userFeed.run();
```

CSS

```
#instafeed a:last-child {
margin-right: 0px;
}
#instafeed {
text-align: center;

}
#instafeed a {
height: 210px;
margin-top: 10px;
width: 210px;
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 40px;
object-fit: cover;
background-size: cover;

}

@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
#instafeed a {
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
}
```

Comment: ..and what is your question?

Comment: See that It's shows with more margin-left on the second row, that's because they are unordered links. I want to make it clean with bootstrap cols.

Comment: remove the margin from last child

Comment: you can add multiple bootstrap class like `col-6 col-md-4` in this way layout change with the window resolution.